# android emulator's wifi says "connected no internet"

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi, emulation

so no internet works on the emulator and also not (of course) for example in my map application (which is probably the reason why the map doesn't load).

why it doesn't work?

android studio 3.2 canary 14, emulator Nexus 5X API 26, i think it is that one x86_64 but x86 didn't work too. Mac OS High Sierra.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you tried this? 
your_path_of_android_sdk\tools\emulator -avd  -dns-server 8.8.8.8

Comment: hm this command /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26_2  -dns-server 8.8.8.8 makes working the wifi ok good but how to do it also without it

Comment: hm so once the emulator is started like that, i can "run" the app normally it seems (from the android studio) and it works

Comment: Unfortunately, this command does not work for me. I'm still stuck with an emulator which thinks it's disconnected from the internet.

Comment: try switching on cold boot, and also restarting your emulator. it noticeably gets f'd up when coming back from sleeping.